# I get an error when I try to upgrade (Kali linux)

Tags: kali-linux

[image: screenshot]

I tried to upgrade searchsploit but it gives me this error:

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit -.mount is masked.
```

And it gives the same error when I try to upgrade any software.

I tried :

```
sudo systemctl unmask packagekit.service

sudo systemctl start packagekit.service
```

But it didn't work

Comment: may be a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: I get this error on Ubuntu 19.04.  Definitely NOT a duplicate of that other error, which looks like hardware problems.  From my reading, `-.mount` is complaining that root "**/**" is not freely writable for `systemd` -- On the surface I see that as a good thing.  Perhaps `packagekit` installer has a problem.  Just to me.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. Gparted was open... after closing it, the problem disappeared.

Comment: This was my case, too.